# How to use a CA (like curl's --cacert) with HTTPie

Tags: ssl, curl, httpie

In curl I can connect with a private key, client cert, and a ca cert like this

```
curl --cert cert.pem --key key.pem --cacert ca.pem https://example.org
```

I can see the --cert and --cert-key options in HTTPie, but how could I use the --cacert option in HTTPie?

I tried combining cert.pem and ca.pem in a new file and using that as my --cert file, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 14):

I got it. In HTTPie you just pass the ca.pem using --verify like this

```
http --cert cert.pem --cert-key key.pem --verify ca.pem http://example.org
```

Answer (score 2):

Only `ca.pem` is required. This is correct request:

```
http --verify /etc/nginx/ssl/myCA.pem https://local.dev
```

Both `ssl_certificate` - `cert.pem` (crt) and `ssl_certificate_key` - `key.pem` (key) should be indicated in server settings, sho you do not need attach them in query.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One additional option is to leverage [HTTPie Configurable options](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/configurable-options) to *automatically* pass the `--verify` flag for any `http` call:

**~/.config/httpie/config.json**

```
{
    "default_options": [
        "--verify=/path/to/ssl/custom_ca_bundle.pem"
    ]
}
```

This way you can continue calling HTTPie without manually passing `--verify` each time!

```
http https://local.dev
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Server: nginx

...
```