# HTTPie mac desktop app: How do I send client cert

Tags: rest, client-certificates, httpie

Recently started using HTTPie desktop app but could not figure out a way to use client certificates. There is a way to do it via the [CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443269/how-to-use-a-ca-like-curls-cacert-with-httpie) but the [official docs](https://httpie.io/docs) do not have information on how to set it up via the desktop UI.